# C++ Converting a String to unsigned char and convert it back to get the string

Tags: c++, string, char, unsigned-char

I hope I have clearly stated my goal in the topic and following is the code I am using.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    const char *data_ptr =(char*)"test";
    const uint8_t* p = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&data_ptr);
    uint8_t* p1= const_cast<uint8_t*>(p);
    char* p2 = reinterpret_cast<char*>(p1);
    const char *final= const_cast<const char*>(p2);
    string s1( data_ptr);
    string s( reinterpret_cast<char const*>(p1),4) ;
    cout<<"data_ptr is "<<data_ptr<<endl;
    cout<<"p "<<p<<endl;
    cout<<"p1 "<<p1<<endl;
    cout<<"p2 "<<p2<<endl;
    cout<<"final is "<<final<<endl;
    cout<<"final1 is "<<s1.size() << "<-->"<<s.size()<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and what it prints is as follows.

```
data_ptr is test
p X@
p1 X@
p2 X@
final is X@
final1 is 4<-->4
```

What should I do to get the "test" as a string.

Comment: Not sure what you're trying to achieve here. You're basically just casting pointers around. Have you tried `std::string(some-of-your-pointer)`? Otherwise, give a bit more context on what you want to do exactly.

Comment: `&data_ptr` is not a pointer to characters, it's a pointer *to the pointer* to some characters.

Comment: ^what joachim said.. also wondering where you got the `const char *data_ptr =(char*)"test";` notation, don't think I've ever seen that `(char*)` cast before?

Comment: @stijn is right about the cast. Per definition, `"test"` is constant anyway, so no cast needed. And Joachim is right about the pointer; that's why the second string (`s`) outputs garbage.

Comment: Yeah my mistake about the pointer. But what I really want to know is to convert a uint8_t array in to a string. I know that there is an array. What I do not know is if it is null terminated. So I was trying to is convert a string to a uint8_t and get the string back from the uint8_t I created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments above, your `data_ptr` cast in line

```
const uint8_t* p = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&data_ptr);
```

casts from a pointer to chars (`char*`) to a pointer of pointer of chars (in your case `uint8_t*`, referencing `&data_ptr`, which is in turn `char*`). That's also why your string `s1` in

```
string s1( data_ptr);
```

Contains the correct `test` string, while `s`, as initialized in

```
string s( reinterpret_cast<char const*>(p1),4) ;
```

with `p1` referencing the wrong pointer to pointer to chars from

```
const uint8_t* p = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&data_ptr);
uint8_t* p1= const_cast<uint8_t*>(p);
```

is just initialized with garbage data.

So just change your line

```
const uint8_t* p = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&data_ptr);
```

to

```
const uint8_t* p = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(data_ptr);
```

and both, `s` and `s1` contain your source string `"test"`.

Answer (score 0):

std::string has a constructor taking a `char*` or `const char*` as a parameter. It also has a function `c_str()` to do the conversion back to a `char*` so all thats needed is this:

```
const char* charptr = "Test";
string str(charptr);
const char* charptr2 = str.c_str();

//just to verify:
cout << charptr << "\n";
cout << str << "\n";
cout << charptr2 << "\n";
```

Edit: As you stated in the comments you need an `uint8_t`, for this just take the raw `char*` as it is:

```
const uint8_t* intptr = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(charptr);
```

Try it online: http://ideone.com/drJYuR

Answer (score 0):

"test" will not fit in an unsigned char.  You should use the standard c functions atoi and itoa to do the conversion.  You can also use these functions if you want to do it character by character.

Comment: He's assigning it to a `const char*`, which is a pointer to a sequence is chars (i.e., an array). There is no issue with his input not fitting into an unsigned char.

Answer (score 0):

I am not entirely sure what you are trying to do here. However, changing

```
const uint8_t* p = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(&data_ptr);
```

to

```
const uint8_t* p = reinterpret_cast<const uint8_t*>(data_ptr);
```

would do the job for you.